# can someone explain this syntax in php for me?

Tags: php, mysql

I just started learning php and the best way to learn is to work on examples..going through this code I still can't understand what it happening here after looking and relooking in my text books..can someone explain this code to me please?

```
$_TABLES['the_list'] =

"`t_id`         varchar(".T_ID_MAX_CHARS.") NOT NULL default '' UNIQUE, ".            
"`tnet`         varchar(".TNET_MAX_CHARS.") NOT NULL default     '".DEFAULT_TNET."', ". 
"`t_version`    int unsigned      NOT NULL default '0', ".                              
"`flag_new`       bool              NOT NULL default '1', ".  
"`flag_used`      bool              NOT NULL default '0', ".  

"`comment`        tinytext          NOT NULL";
```

what does the syntax "$variable[something]" do?

Comment: `$variable[something]` => [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: This code is for making table in database

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$variable` is array variable, `[something]` is stand for array index with the value is the SQL query inside `"`. So you can check it with `var_dump($variable['something']);`

Answer (score 1):

According to what I see,
there is a variable called `_TABLES` which is an array
It is defining a key called `the_list` within this, which contains the text to generate a table in a MySQL database

MORE INFO: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.
>
> ```
> array(
>     key  => value,
>     key2 => value2,
>     key3 => value3,
>      ... )
> ```

**PD:** You have to be more specific because you're asking something without context.